# How to simplify the result of this indefinite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

There is an indefinite integral:

$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+10 x^2-96 x-71}} \, dx$$

Mathematica 13 can handle it and evaluate this integral analytically if we enter:

`Integrate[x/Sqrt[x^4 + 10*x^2 - 96*x - 71], x] // ToRadicals`

But the result is too large and I don't know how to simplify it (I tried Simplify and FullSimplify, but didn't help).

In Maple 2021 it's much easier. You just need to write:

`simplify(int(x/sqrt(x^4 + 10*x^2 - 96*x - 71), x, method = Trager))`

and you will get:

$\frac{1}{8}\ln \! \left(\left(x^{6}+15 x^{4}-80 x^{3}+27 x^{2}-528 x +781\right) \sqrt{x^{4}+10 x^{2}-96 x -71}+x^{8}+20 x^{6}-128 x^{5}+54 x^{4}-1408 x^{3}+3124 x^{2}+10001\right)$

Comment: You are not showing the large result, but from the description I would think you are using version 12 rather than 13 for this integral.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, [Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/2SVBqYCn/Screenshot.png)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, ```$Version``` ```"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"```

Comment: That's definitely a version 12 and prior type of result. If you have 13 try this: `SetSystemOptions[
 "IntegrateOptions" -> {"IntegrateAlgebraicTimeConstraint" -> 100}]` and see if that improves things.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, yes, now it is working! thanks
![](https://i.postimg.cc/j2MTVC39/S.png)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, can you write this comment again, but as an answer, so that I choose it as the best answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is code for handling indefinte algebraic integrals that is new to version 13. It is based on code [IntegrateAlgebraic](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IntegrateAlgebraic/) in the Wolfram Function Repository and was written by the same person (Sam Blake).

We use a time constraint to keep it from grinding its gears and in some cases this might be too small to get a result. In particular there will be examploes, such as from this post, where some processors will complete the computation in this code but others will not.

As a workaround when encountering this issue, this time constraint is configurable as a system option.

```
In[669]:= "IntegrateOptions" /. SystemOptions[]

Out[669]= {"IntegrateAlgebraicTimeConstraint" -> 10, 
 "RubiTimeConstraint" -> 5, "UseIntegrateAlgebraic" -> True, 
 "UseRubiIntegrate" -> True}
```

If you want to increase the value above 10 you might do for example:

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "IntegrateOptions" -> {"IntegrateAlgebraicTimeConstraint" -> 100}];
```

Comment: "Some CPUs" not quite: in fact you need 20 seconds to integrate this another Chebyshev-Zolotarev integral in elementary functions: Integrate[x/Sqrt[x^4-2x^3+3x^2+4x+1], x]

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

int = Integrate[x/Sqrt[x^4 + 10*x^2 - 96*x - 71], x]

(* -(1/8) Log[-10001 - 3124 x^2 + 1408 x^3 - 54 x^4 + 128 x^5 - 20 x^6 - x^8 + 
   Sqrt[-71 - 96 x + 10 x^2 + 
     x^4] (781 - 528 x + 27 x^2 - 80 x^3 + 15 x^4 + x^6)] *)

intR = Integrate[x/Sqrt[x^4 + 10*x^2 - 96*x - 71], x, 
   Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals];
```

The results are **identical** with or without the `Assumptions`

```
int === intR

(* True *)
```

The result that you report from Maple

```
intMaple = 1/8*
      Log[(x^6 + 15 x^4 - 80 x^3 + 27 x^2 - 528 x + 781)*
      Sqrt[x^4 + 10 x^2 - 96 x - 71] +
     x^8 + 20 x^6 - 128 x^5 + 54 x^4 - 1408 x^3 + 3124 x^2 + 10001];
```

There is little difference in their complexity

```
LeafCount /@ {int, intMaple}

(* {78, 76} *)
```

They are equivalent anti-derivatives

```
D[int, x] == D[intMaple, x] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Since you are taking the indefinite integral (anti-derivative), results are equivalent if they differ by only a constant (which can be complex).

The two results differ by a piecewise complex constant

```
ReImPlot[int - intMaple, {x, -10, 10},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["ReIm", {.8, .4}]]
```

[image]

```
int - intMaple /. x -> 5/2 // FullSimplify

(* (I π)/8 + Log[1/(4 3^(7/8))] *)

% // N

(* -2.34758 + 0.392699 I *)

int - intMaple /. x -> 5 // FullSimplify

(* -((I π)/8) + Log[1/(4 3^(7/8))] *)

% // N

(* -2.34758 - 0.392699 I *)
```

Comment: [Screenshot.png](https://postimg.cc/cvGJjVgJ)

Comment: With `v13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)` I get the same results as shown for v13.0.1. Have you tried starting with a fresh kernel or restarting Mathematica.

Comment: Yes, I've tried everything, it doesn't help.

Comment: Try using `RootReduce` on your result. `FullSimplify` may time out before getting to `RootReduce`

Comment: Perhaps, Mathematica for Mac OS is better than Mathematica for Windows

Comment: With your version, try using [`Rubi`](https://rulebasedintegration.org/)

Comment: I believe the part of Rubi that is built into Mathematica will not give a decent result on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is only correct for a real variable.

In MMA variables are assumed to be complex. If you want to restrict the variable to be real, you need to specify this, like:

```
Integrate[x/Sqrt[x^4 + 10*x^2 - 96*x - 71], x, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't help, I get the same large output

Comment: You will see a spot on the Sun, executing `Plot[{Im[x/Sqrt[x^4 + 10*x^2 - 96*x - 71]], 
  Im[1/8 Log[-10001 - 3124 x^2 + 1408 x^3 - 54 x^4 + 128 x^5 - 
      20 x^6 - x^8 + 
      Sqrt[-71 - 96 x + 10 x^2 + x^4] *(781 - 528 x + 27 x^2 - 
         80 x^3 + 15 x^4 + x^6)]]}, {x, -1/2, 4}]`.

Comment: @Daniel Huber, I don't get the same result as in your image if I enter ```Integrate[x/Sqrt[x^4 + 10*x^2 - 96*x - 71], x, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]```. Did you just copy-paste the Maple's answer and take a screenshot?

Comment: This is the output I get from MMA version 13.0.1. Could it be a version problem?

Comment: @DanielHuber, 
```$Version```
```"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"```

Comment: @DanielHuber, [Screenshot.png](https://postimg.cc/cvGJjVgJ)

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I get the same long result for `"12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)"` even with `Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals` but the nicer short version for 13.0.1.0.  So it sounds like it's time to upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the solution I obtained.

[image]

Comment: Please look at the other answers to see how to improve your answer. Use code as much as possible, using pictures only when these add value.

Comment: This is precisly what we were trying to avoid, i.e. non elementary antiderivative.